# Debugging with VS2013 & IIS 8

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, iis-8

I'm sorry if this seems a very basic question but its something I've not struggled with in the past but seem to be having massive problems with now.

I have recently got a new dev laptop running Windows 8, I have installed IIS 8 as well as upgrading to Visual Studio 2013 from VS2010. I've been working on a new project using MVC5 and EF6 which sits in the inetpub/wwwroot/mynewproject folder.

The problem Im having though it attaching a debugger to IIS (w3wp.exe) in VS2010 it was simple the w3wp process showed in the available processes list I selected it and away we went. In VS2013 it doesn't show in the list by default I have to tick the Show processes from all users checkbox and when I try to attach I get a error stating the following:

Unable to attach to the process. The microsoft visual studio remote debugging monitor (MSVSMON.exe) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be caused beacuse a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer. blah blah....

All I want to do is debug my project by attaching to the w3wp process, is there some basic configuration I'm missing here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: alternative:see project properties. Web Tab. Set the project to use Local IIS instead of Express. You can then Launch IIS using the debug run option. It attaches for you.

Comment: Are you attaching to a remote computer, or the local one? Are you running Visual Studio as an administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run Visual Studio as Administrator in order to attach to the w3wp.exe process.

Comment: this answer saved me a lot of time